# Trainig ckpt in tensorflow object detection

Tags: python, tensorflow

Can i ask if this is normal?

I0105 14:21:41.290731  1512 model_lib_v2.py:705] Step 19400 per-step time 0.530s
INFO:tensorflow:{'Loss/classification_loss': 313630.25,
'Loss/localization_loss': 1025.6028,
'Loss/regularization_loss': 10148650000.0,
'Loss/total_loss': 10148964000.0,
'learning_rate': 0.5674639}
I0105 14:21:41.293730  1512 model_lib_v2.py:708] {'Loss/classification_loss': 313630.25,
'Loss/localization_loss': 1025.6028,
'Loss/regularization_loss': 10148650000.0,
'Loss/total_loss': 10148964000.0,
'learning_rate': 0.5674639}

Comment: The learnig rate is always 0.42s to 0.532s. My training batch size is 1 because i dont have GPU.  MY MODEL SSD_MOBILENET_V2_320X320

Comment: Can you include more details about the model like what kind of a model it is, what loss function and optimizer was used and some details about the dataset used for training the model?